# CPLEX OPL - How to read a set of variable length from Excel

Tags: excel, cplex, opl

I want to read a tuple from my Excel file for my OPL model in CPLEX, which has the following format:

```
tuple A {
  string a;
  int b;
  {string} c;
}
```

The set `{string} c` of each tuple element is of variable length.

How can I read this via SheetConnection or is this not possible?

I've tried to read it via named fields in Excel, but that didn't work. 
I have also read on the CPLEX documentation, that it is only possible to read tuples of fixed width, but my data is not of fixed width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the number of tuples, you could read 2 arrays with SheetRead

One for

```
string a;
  int b;
```

The second for

```
{string} c;
```

For that array you could use the max number of strings.

And then in the .mod you turn those 2 arrays into a tuple set.